# For Each Gridview not working properly

Tags: vb.net, linq

Can you help me on my **for each loop** it only saves the first row many times of the Gridview on my database. Can you please help me if what's wrong on my code. Thanks in advance.

here is my code

```
 Using _adTransPlatts As New TradingTransactionRepository

        For Each row As GridViewRow In 
              GridView1.Rows_adTransPlatts.AddPlatts(GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Text, GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Text, GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Text)
        Next
             MsgBox("Completed")
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change *GridView1.Rows(0)* by **currentRow**

```
 For Each currentRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        _adTransPlatts.AddPlatts(currentRow.Cells(1).Text, currentRow.Cells(2).Text, currentRow.Cells(3).Text)
 Next
```

GridView1.Rows(0) refers always to the first row